# React refresh webpack plugin throws $RefreshSig$ is not defined error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, hot-reload

I'm using webpack-hot-middleware approach and after setup I get u**ncaught ReferenceError: $RefreshSig$ is not defined** error thrown in console.

webpack.config.js looks like this:

for modules:

```
    {
      test: 'ts',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
          options: {
            plugins: [buildMode === 'development' && require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')].filter(Boolean),
          },
        },
      ],
    },
```

and above it I create ant plugin instance:

```
new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
```

Comment: You need a second plugins key at the same level as test, exclude, etc. If that is missing then I believe you will get this error. You can see what I mean in the docs here https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the [github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin) docs, Probably your error is in `const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';`.

Check where you are doing this logic. Make sure you have the `env vars` defined where you call `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

In my case, I put this logic inside `webpack` config, because I recieve `env` from `CLI`.

My build script:

```json
"build:prd": "webpack --config webpack.prod.config.js --env NODE_ENV=production"
```

My `webpack.config` file looks like:

```js
module.exports = (env) => {
  const isDevelopment = env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

  const babelOptions = {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
    plugins: [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
      '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
      isDevelopment && require.resolve('react-refresh/babel'),
    ].filter(Boolean),
  };

  return {
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: babelOptions,
            },
            {
              loader: 'ts-loader',
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: babelOptions,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
      alias: {
        '@utils': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/utils'),
      },
    },
    ],
  };
};
```

My plugin `ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin` is separeted in another webpack, exclusive for dev. So, I decide to put the plugin only in `webpack.dev.conf` without `if` to verify the environment, but if you follow the docs and be careful with `env vars`, will work.

I hope this helps you. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
const mode = process.env.WEBPACK_SERVE ? 'development' : 'production';
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', mode!='production' && require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')].filter(Boolean),
          },
        },
      },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `react-refresh-webpack-plugin` [docs](https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin),You should use plugin `ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin`,not `webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin`.

```
plugins: [isDevelopment && new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin()].filter(Boolean),
```